# Compare Prospect email in Journey to Core data and record a Goal Conversion

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, goals

I created a Journey and imported prospects to a DE to be injected into the Journey.  I import customer data from our CRM everyday that includes all accounts.  My "prospects" are customers that did loan apps with us in the past but never completed the process so are not current customers in the account database/CRM.   Can the Goal look for email address in the Journey and then look for a match in the core data and see a match/goal conversion?   How do I create that?   Thanks

Comment: is the CRM salesforce? and do you have datastream enabled?

Comment: Is the CRM import creating a new subscriberkey?  Or are you using email address as the subscriberkey?  If the import is generating new subscribers based on a different key, you won't be able to this type of goal tracking in the JB UI since you'd be doing a lookup against your JB entry audience (which is not supported)